# Знаки препинания в предложении: "Он проснулся и(,) будто что-то вспомнив(,) быстро оделся и выбежал из комнаты"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки в предложении.

> Он проснулся и, будто что-то вспомнив, быстро оделся и выбежал из комнаты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласна с пунктуацией,предложенной автором вопроса. Трудный момент в этом предложении - перед первым И. На первый взгляд,  здесь повторяющийся союз  И, соединяющий однородные сказуемые. Сомнения понятны: однородные сказуемые надо разделить запятой. Но союз И соединяет здесь первое сказуемое и два других, объединенных в пару. Это понятно по смыслу (= когда вспомнил, оделся и выбежал). Да и ,если убрать оборот, никакой перечислительной интонации не возникает.

Answer (score 3):

Знаки поставлены правильно. Первый союз И соединяет  сказуемое ПРОСНУЛСЯ и  конструкцию с однородными сказуемыми ОДЕЛСЯ и ВЫБЕЖАЛ, к которым относится  обстоятельство БУДТО ЧТО-ТО ВСПОМНИВ.

Comment: С пунктуацией согласна, но при чём здесь детерминант?Детерминант – это словоформа, которая не зависит от подлежащего или сказуемого, а распространяет все предложение в целом. Обычно находится в абсолютном начале предложения.Не отделяется запятой, если не является деепричастным оборотом. Гуляя по лесу, мы собирали ягоды. А здесь обычный деепричастный оборот, относящийся к паре однородных сказуемых - оделся и выбежал.

Comment: Согласна).

Comment: Интересно, а из чего делается вывод, что деепричастный оборот относится к двум однородным сказуемым?! 
А если даже и так, разве есть в правилах оговорки насчет пунктуации в подобных случаях?!

Comment: В данном случае пунктуация останется прежней. Не поняла, что Вас не устраивает в моём комментарии. Вы деепричастный оборот тоже считаете детерминантом? Катерина со мной согласилась и ответ исправила, а Вы против? Флаг Вам в руки, считайте, но это грубая ошибка, откройте любой вузовский учебник современного русского языка.В школьных это не изучают.